# How to only run tests when an argument is set in nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I only want a particular test to run when an argument "beta" = true is set in the command line when running the nightwatch tests. How do I only run a test if a environment variable is set using nightwatch.js?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make use of the `tags` feature of NightwatchJS

```
module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['beta']

  'Your test here': function(browser) {
     // your code here..
  }
}
```

and execute your test like

```
$ nightwatch --tag beta
```